# Dates imported from Excel into R produce different results when converted to character in different ways

Tags: r

Import an Excel spreadsheet containing dates into R (using readxl).  E.g.

```
`# A tibble: 9 x 2
     id       date
  <dbl>     <dttm>
1     1 2000-01-23
2     2 2000-01-24
3     3 2000-01-25
4     4 2000-01-26
5     5 2000-01-27
6     6 2000-01-28
7     7 2000-01-29
8     8 2000-01-30
9     9 2000-01-31`
```

Now convert the date column to characters:

1. Use $

`> as.character(dat$date)
[1] "2000-01-23" "2000-01-24" "2000-01-25" "2000-01-26" "2000-01-27" "2000-01-28" "2000-01-29" "2000-01-30" "2000-01-31"`

2. Use [[ ]]

`> as.character(dat[[2]])
[1] "2000-01-23" "2000-01-24" "2000-01-25" "2000-01-26" "2000-01-27" "2000-01-28" "2000-01-29" "2000-01-30" "2000-01-31"`

3. Use [ , ]

`> as.character(dat[ , 2])
[1] "c(948585600, 948672000, 948758400, 948844800, 948931200, 949017600, 949104000, 949190400, 949276800)"`

Why does the third case produce different results? I believe the first 2 cases return vectors and the third case returns a dataframe, but why does that make a difference? And where do the numbers in case 3 come from? (These numbers don't correspond with the numbers used by Excel to represent dates.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is because you have a `tibble`, not a `data.frame`. A `data.frame` will by default reduce to a vector if the subsetting will return a single column or single row; you can opt to use `drop=F` (see below) to prevent this.

This is considered a "good feature" in the `tidyverse`-based packages: do one thing, always return the same class/structure, etc. Functions that return a `list` or a `vector` in a way that programmatically may not have been predicted can be considered a problem. (Because of this, when I'm dealing *programmatically* in raw `data.frame` vice `tbls`, I often add `,drop=FALSE` when I need to guard against it.)

> On a similar note, have you ever been bitten by `sapply` or `mapply`? If the returned values are all the same length/class, then you get a `vector` or a `matrix`, but if any length or class is not the same then you get a `list`, whether you are expecting it or not. This is one justification for "always" using `sapply(..., simplify=FALSE)` or `lapply(...)` or `mapply(..., SIMPLIFY=FALSE)`. It's also partial-justification for the `purrr::map` family of functions.

Examples:

```
library(dplyr)
d1 <- data.frame(dt=seq.Date(as.Date('2000-01-23'),as.Date('2000-01-30'),by='day'))
d2 <- as.tbl(d1)

d1[,1]
# [1] "2000-01-23" "2000-01-24" "2000-01-25" "2000-01-26" "2000-01-27"
# [6] "2000-01-28" "2000-01-29" "2000-01-30"
d2[,1]
# # A tibble: 8 × 1
#           dt
#       <date>
# 1 2000-01-23
# 2 2000-01-24
# 3 2000-01-25
# 4 2000-01-26
# 5 2000-01-27
# 6 2000-01-28
# 7 2000-01-29
# 8 2000-01-30
```

Why does this create something funky? Because of something else you have in the data.

```
d1$id <- 1:nrow(d1)
d2$id <- 1:nrow(d2)
as.character(d2)
# [1] "c(10979, 10980, 10981, 10982, 10983, 10984, 10985, 10986)"
# [2] "1:8"                                                      
as.character(d1[,1])
# [1] "2000-01-23" "2000-01-24" "2000-01-25" "2000-01-26" "2000-01-27"
# [6] "2000-01-28" "2000-01-29" "2000-01-30"
as.character(d1[,1,drop=FALSE])
# [1] "c(10979, 10980, 10981, 10982, 10983, 10984, 10985, 10986)"
as.character(d2[,1])
# [1] "c(10979, 10980, 10981, 10982, 10983, 10984, 10985, 10986)"
```

When you call a function on a whole frame (whether `tibble` or not), it often converts all columns to the lowest-common format, `character < numeric < integer`, and `POSIXt` are effectively `numeric` (with tz info), so it is coerced into a `numeric`. since there is non-`POSIXt` in it. (This applies equally to `POSIXt` and `Date` classes.)

(As to the actual numbers they get coerced to, I don't know off-hand ...)